# Qt: How to clean up a QThread when you do not subclass it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

If I have the most standard code of using a QThread like this:

```
myClass* object = new myClass();
QThread* worker = new QThread();
object->moveToThread(worker);
worker->start();
```

Then what is the proper way to delete *object* and the proper way to quit the *worker* thread?

If I don't delete *object* there will be memory leakage.

If I don't quit *worker*, when I close the application, there will be warning said that QThread is destroyed while it is still running.

Comment: Do you know about [QtConcurrent::run](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html)? It uses a thread pool, and you just give it a function to execute in a different thread. Much easier than using QThread.

Comment: @sashoalm I know we can subclass a QThread and rewrite the run function, and it will triggered by the start() call, but not in deep.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood what I was telling you.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said QThread::run, not very familiar with QtConcurrent::run.

Comment: Then I advise you to familiarize yourself with it. It'll save you time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete your `object` object, you can connect the [`QThread::finished`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#finished) signal of your `worker` object to the [`QObject::deleteLater`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#deleteLater) slot of your `object` object.

And to quit your thread, you can call [`QThread::quit`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#quit) and [`QThread::wait`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#wait) in the destructor of your class (or whenever you need to stop your thread).

```
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    thread->quit();
    thread->wait();
    ...
}
```

To delete your `worker` object, you can just set a parent to it, or make it an automatic member variable. You can also use a smart pointer for it.

By the way, your naming convention is a bit odd. The `QThread` object in your case is not a worker, it just manages the thread. The `myClass` object would be the worker in your case.

Comment: What's the difference between quit() and terminate() in this case?

Comment: @saZ Are you trying to wait in the thread? `thread()` returns the current thread of the object. You would wait there for ever since you are blocking the thread there. You should wait in the destructor of the the class that is using `myClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic usage:

Define a worker class:

```
class MyWorkerClass {
    signals:
    void Finished();

    public slots:
    void RunCode(){
        //...
        // add your code here
        //...
        emit Finished();
    }
}
```

How to use your worker class:

```
MyWorkerClass * workerObject = new MyWorkerClass();
QThread * workerThread = new QThread();

workerObject->moveToThread(workerThread);

connect(workerThread, &QThread::started, workerObject, &MyWorkerClass::RunCode);
connect(workerObject, &MyWorkerClass::Finished, workerThread, &QThread::quit);

workerThread->start();
workerObject->deleteLater();
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Connecting `QThread::finished` and  `QObject::deleteLater` is wrong. If signal `QThread::finished` is emitted  this means that thread event loop will not run again so slot `QObject::deleteLater` will not be called. So accepted answer is wrong.</s>

It is better to do it like that:

```
myClass* object = new myClass();
QThread* worker = new QThread(parent);
object->moveToThread(worker);

connect(object, &QObject::destroyed, worker, &QThread::quit, Qt::DirectConnection);
connect(someObject, SIGNAL(stoItSignal()), object, &QObject::deleteLater);
worker->start();
```

At some point it might be needed to wait for tread,  (for example when main window is destroyed) to clean up things, so this statement could be useful (in this case `Qt::DirectConnection` in code above is obligatory):

```
object->deleteLater();
worker->wait(3000);
```

Comment: The docs say: [*From Qt 4.8 onwards, it is possible to deallocate objects that live in a thread that has just ended, by connecting the finished() signal to QObject::deleteLater().*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#managing_thread). So it is not wrong. The docs also state about `QThread::finished`: [*When this signal is emitted, the event loop has already stopped running. No more events will be processed in the thread, except for deferred deletion events. This signal can be connected to QObject::deleteLater(), to free objects in that thread.*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#finished)